# Two static IPs from Comcast to two devices. How to connect?

Tags: networking

I have a car wash that has equipment running that must have a static IP.  I also want to view my cameras from home.  I have a comcast connection and they have given me two static IP's.  What is the best way to do this.  Can I put in two routers off a switch connected to my comcast box?

Answer (score 1):

Do not waste two static IPs on this. Just use one router, to the WAN side of which you will assign one of the two static IPs (keeping the other for future needs), and connect your equipment to the LAN side of the router if the number of cables is smaller than the number of gates available on the router, or buy a cheap switch (not a hub, careful) as per the number of cables, then draw one cable from the switch to one of the LAN-side gates of the router.

In order to view the cameras from remote you will have to do some port forwarding, the internet is replete with instructions on how to do it.